# Modules communication inside application by something like servicebus

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, architecture

We need to build a destop application.
Operator works with a list of shops. He has a main window where he filters shops and he has a number of extra windows: map(shows location of shops, marks the selected shop from list as bold on map), stock form(queries external service for stock of selected shop).
The forms can be opened simultaneously or some of them can be hidden, except main form.

**Possible Implementation**:
I consider each form as standalone module of my application. Why? I expect that number of forms will grow. For example, new form for latest sales in shop, another form for a chat with shop manager.

**Questions**:
How do I organize communications between modules?
For now I have an idea to use a shared bus and modules can send and receive messages throught it.
Are there any alternatives?
Are there any implementation of this bus or I'm enough with straight forward implementation build upon publisher/subscriber pattern?

Comment: Both MVVM Light and ReactiveUI WPF MVVM libraries have message buses that you might find useful. Others exist as well. http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/02/25/reactiveui-message-bus-decoupling-objects-using-the-publishsubscribe-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to keep the modules decoupled. Otherwise, it will result with a hell of dependencies between modules.
To achieve this, best offer is using an EventAggregator structure. Though the name seems as event, in fact, it's a bus structure to manage pub/sub.

You can find information about EventAggregator pattern form [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html).

.NET world have an opensource API (named [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)) providing this capability. I strongly suggest you to read the Event Aggregation section of Prism documentation from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) and digg the source code.

Currently we are developing a Silverlight application which is including different modules totally decoupled from each other (no module knows instance/reference of the other one) and communicating via Prism API.