# Pattern for modular UI and event management

Tags: design-patterns

In my application, I have different classes for UI components and for their event management.

While my initial thought is to have separate classes for Window and Frames and then a Window would have composition of Frames.

And there should be a single entry for creation and delegation of the events happening either at Window or Frame/Control level.

However, I'm unable to conclude on a pattern of this sort.

So, currently ending up with separate event handlers which are directly linked to their respective UI frames/controls.

Please guide my in selecting a good pattern for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EventAggregator](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern should be your way to go. It totally decouples your modules from each other. By this way, modules don't need to know(or reference) of the other one.

You can see my another (more detailed) answer about the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775654/1313030).

If you don't need that much loose coupling (e.g. modules have the reference to each other), you should take a look at [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). It is another method to implement distributed event handling mechanisms.

Comment: Might be my opinion for selecting this pattern, but it more of an extension to the command pattern, the extra benefit it brought about was the assimilation of components without a strict enforcement of protocol that Command pattern was bringing in

Comment: Exactly! As an additional information, i suggest you to read QT API documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and the [article](http://www.elpauer.org/stuff/a_deeper_look_at_signals_and_slots.pdf) explaining its signal-slot mechanism which is based on observer pattern as another good implementation of distributed event handling.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`Command`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern. Command pattern basically lets you encapsulate a request/message  into a full fledged object so that the object requesting the message doesn't have to know about the object that will ultimately handle the request. For example you have menu items , buttons etc that can emit events and basically when you are coding these elements , you do not know who is going to handle these events ( I am presuming you are developing a UI framework that will handle events ). So you basically encode the information regarding the receiver of the event inside a class called `Command` and it will have a reference to the actual receiver . It will also have an `execute` method  that will basically invoke domain specific code. You will have various subclasses of Command class that will handle specific requests like `CopyCommand`, `PasteCommand` etc .

```
abstract class Command {
  private Receiver receiver;
  public void setReceiver(Rceceiver receiver){
     this.receiver = receiver;
  }

  public Rceiver getReceiver(){
     return this.receiver;
   }

  abstract execute();
}
```

Basically now you can set Commands with individual `UI` components using the `setCommand` api . The UI components will just delegate to the underlying command .

```
class Button {

private Command command; 

public void setCommand(Command command){
 this.command = command;
} 

 public void onClick(){
    command.execute();
  }
}
```

For more details look at the command pattern in the Gof Book.